# I have made a login form but i not able to do validation with Javascript code

Tags: javascript, validation

I have made a login form and I wanted to validate the form. So at first, I used PHP validations, but I wanted to learn something new so I have chosen javascript validations. I am not able to form the program. please help me out.

```js
const email = document.getElementById('email')
const password = document.getElementById('password')
const form = document.getElementById('login')
const errorElement = document.getElementsByClassName('alert')

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  let messages = []
  if (email.value && password.value === '' || email.value && password.value == null) {
    messages.push('Enter the Data')
  }

  if (messages.length > 0) {
    e.preventDefault()
    errorElement.innerText = messages.join(', ')
  }

})
```

```html
<div class="login">
  <h1>Login</h1>
  <div class="alert">
    <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
  </div>
  <form id="login" name="login" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="email">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login" name="login">
    <input type="button" value="Register" onclick="location.href= 'register.php'">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the error you get or what screen is display after submit

Comment: nothing is happening!! it is not showing any error in the console too...

Comment: Probably the values aren’t `null`? An empty field may contain “”. Also the errorElements variable is an array, you need to use `errorElements[0].innerText`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if condition in the validation is not valid:

```
email.value && password.value === '' || email.value && password.value == null
```

You cannot check if two values are empty at the same time, and since the field is a text field they can never be null. You can do:

```
email.value === '' || password.value === ''
```

Or chain multiple ifs to have separate messages:

```js
const email = document.getElementById('email')
const password = document.getElementById('password')
const form = document.getElementById('login')

// Be carefule, getElementsByClassName returns an array, not a single element
const errorElement = document.getElementsByClassName('alert')[0]
// If you always want a single element you can use 
// const errorElement = document.querySelector('.alert')

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  let messages = []
  errorElement.innerText = '';
  errorElement.parentElement.style.display = 'none';

  if (email.value === '') {
    messages.push('Empty email');
  }
  if (password.value === '') {
    messages.push('Empty password');
  }

  if (messages.length > 0) {
    e.preventDefault()
    errorElement.innerText = messages.join(', ');
    errorElement.parentElement.style.display = 'block';
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="login">
  <h1>Login</h1>
  <div style="display:none;">
    <span class="alert"></span>
    <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
  </div>
  <form id="login" name="login" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="email">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login" name="login">
    <input type="button" value="Register" onclick="location.href= 'register.php'">
  </form>
</div>
```

**Update**
I have added a basic example on how to hide/show the errors.

Comment: But, What if i want to display a validation that enter 'All your Field is Empty' something like?

Comment: You could do this then: `if (email.value === '' && password.value === '')`

Comment: It have  shown the error as I have to add double quotes to getelementbyId function while storing it in a constant

Comment: And I have the error div which is not going when I am loading the page. So there any method that when there is any error then only it will appear or else it will be disable

Comment: I have added an example of that

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

You are trying to check two values at same time. Hope it works for you

```
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    let messages = []
    if (email.value === '' && password.value === '' || email.value == null && password.value == null){
        messages.push('Enter the Data')
    }

    if(messages.length > 0){
        errorElement.innerText = messages.join(', ')
    }
})
```

Comment: This one actually, I did but still it was not showing me!!

Comment: the validation which i wanted to see.

Comment: Try `console.log(messages)` after if the condition close

Comment: i think this not allow = const email = document.getElementById('email')

Comment: document.getElementById("email") - after doing this everything is working....does qoutes matter in js??

Comment: Yes `const` element is actually a constant that can not be replaced, you have to use `var`